# Remove Activity Indicator subview from UIButton view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I built a interface with several buttons. The buttons pull info from the internet for their title. I add a UIActivityIndicator to each button  in the view like so:

```
- (void) addActivityIndicator {
    UIButton * button;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:i];
        NSLog(@"Button: %i",i);
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.enabled = NO;

         UIActivityIndicatorView * buttonSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [buttonSpinner startAnimating];
        buttonSpinner.tag = i;
        buttonSpinner.frame = button.bounds;
        [button addSubview:buttonSpinner];
    }

}
```

However, I cant seem to access individual indicators to remove them.

```
[(UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:tag] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self addTitle:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[(UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:tag] setEnabled:YES];
[(UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:tag] [buttonSpinner stopAnimating]];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:i];
        NSLog(@"Button: %i",i);
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.enabled = NO;

         UIActivityIndicatorView * buttonSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [buttonSpinner startAnimating];
        buttonSpinner.tag = i*99;
        buttonSpinner.frame = button.bounds;
        [button addSubview:buttonSpinner];
    }
```

Then, get the `UIActivityIndicatorView`

```
[(UIActivityIndicatorView *)[(UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:tag] viewWithTag:tag] stopAnimating];
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that before but get the error `[UIButton stopAnimating]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Yes. I think the issue exists that the button tag and the indicator tag are the same.

Comment: I don't think because they are same. Did you change title of the button successfully?

Comment: I have discovered that if the UIButtons's tag and the UIActivityIndicatorView's tag are the same, your method fails. However, if  Alter the Indicator view's tag ( example tag*99) then your method works fine.

Comment: @@!. Anyway, the problem is fixed. So weird.

Comment: @Firemarble thank you. I will update my answer with tag*99 tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try iterating through subviews and removing it?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

UIActivityIndicatorView *toRemove;
for (UIView *view in button.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]])
    {
        toRemove = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)view;
        break;
    }
}
[toRemove removeFromSuperview];
```